# EMF Model ecore Diagram eclipse, how to do a two way relation

Tags: eclipse, emf

I'm trying to do my first Model with `ecore` diagram and I didn't find a way to draw a relationship between two class with any direction on it. In other words, any arrow symbol on the extremity of it.

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a reference from the first class to the second. Call it ref1, for example. Then create another reference in the opposite direction - from the second class to the first - and set its "opposite" property to ref1.